# FileWriter crea fichero en blanco

Tags: java

Es un porgrama muy simple, repite lo que escribes hasta que pones para, y si le dices guarda, guarda todo lo que has escrito en un txt, el problema es que ese txt siempre me sale en blanco y no se por que ya que he usado mas veces la misma forma de guardar archivos

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("texto.txt");
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            String texto = "";
            String aux;
            System.out.println("Teclee para para parar o guardar para guardar");
            do{
                aux = teclado.nextLine();
                switch(aux){
                    default:
                        System.out.println(aux);
                        texto += aux+"\r\n";
                        break;
                    case "guardar":
                        fw.write(texto);
                        System.out.println("Guardado");
                        break;
                    case "para":
                        break;
                }
            }while(!aux.equalsIgnoreCase("para"));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `write()` sólo manda algo al writer para que lo almacene, pero no hace la escritura, por eso el fichero está en blanco. Para que los datos realmente se escriban, debes invocar al método `flush()` del mismo.

Y no olvides hacer `fw.close()` al final para cerrarlo.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("texto.txt");
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            String texto = "";
            String aux;
            System.out.println("Teclee para para parar o guardar para guardar");
            do{
                aux = teclado.nextLine();
                switch(aux.toLowerCase()){
                    default:
                        System.out.println(aux);
                        texto += aux+"\r\n";
                        break;
                    case "guardar":
                        fw.write(texto);
                        fw.flush()
                        System.out.println("Guardado");
                        break;
                    case "para":
                        fw.close();
                        break;
                }
            }while(!aux.equalsIgnoreCase("para"));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado, he hecho muchos mas programas del tipo porque estoy aprendiendo todavia y en ninguno hemos utilizado flush, siempre se me guardaba perfectamente, el fw.close() se me olvido pero creo que a partir de java 7 el catch IOException lo hace solo

Comment: @Adrian Rodríguez te equivocas con el try con recursos (que se parece pero lo que tienes en tu código no lo es) te dejo un tutorial sobre como usarlo https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html puedes usarlo en todos los objetos que tengan la interfaz autocloseable() (fiijate en el javadoc si quieres saber si un objeto tiene esta interfaz)

Comment: Genial. Marca la respuesta como válida, entonces. Respecto a lo que comentas, puede que en vez de FileWriter usases BufferedWriter, que sí es cierto que no necesita un flush() explícito.