# De ArrayList<> a JSON

Tags: json, arraylist, gson

Tengo un ArrayList<> formado por objetos de una clase llamada 'Alumno', datos que he recogido pidiéndolos por teclado.
Bien, ahora tengo la intención de crear un archivo '.json' en el cual se escriba toda la información recogida en el ArrayList listaAlumnos...
He creado un objeto de Gson, por supuesto con la anterior importación de la libreria 'gson-2.6.2.jar', y con este objeto y la clase '.toJson' he transformado listaAlumnos en un array de tipo Json para crear el archivo... o ese es el que yo pienso que es el primer paso... ¿Cómo puedo crear un archivo .json en el que se escriba la lista de este array??

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String JSON = gson.toJson(listaAlumnos);
```

Comment: Ya tienes el json ¿Cuál es el problema?. ¿Revisaste [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)?

Comment: El problema es que necesito que ese json se escriba en un File de '.json' y que eso lo único que hace es imprimirme por consola

Comment: Entonces con un `FileWriter` es suficiente, revisa [este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171291/filewriter-crea-fichero-en-blanco).

Comment: Tú puedes intentar esto simplemente: `gson.toJson(listaAlumnos, new FileWriter(rutaYNombreDelArchivo));` Esto debería crearte el archivo deseado, sabiendo que debes cambiar `rutaYNombreDelArchivo` por una ruta válida dando al archivo una extensión `.json`  claro está. Revisa el [tutorial de Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-save-file) para más detalles.